# Wrong output while merging Two Sorted Lists

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I have tried to merge two *sorted lists* into one and print that list using display method. But I am getting, I am getting this output:

```
-1 --> -21 --> 0 --> 2 --> 3 --> 5 --> 44 --> null
```

instead of:

```
-21 --> 0 --> 2 --> 3 --> 5 --> 44 --> null
```

Why am I getting this extra `-1` before? I know that I have in line 15  `ListNode dummy= new ListNode(-1);` which I have initialized with `-1`. Is it the same `-1` that I am getting? How do I skip this?

Here is my code :

```
public class Mergelists {
    private static ListNode head;

    private static class ListNode{
        int val;
        ListNode next;

        public ListNode(int val){
            this.val= val;
            this.next= null;
        }
    }

        public static ListNode merge(ListNode l1, ListNode l2){
            ListNode dummy = new ListNode(-1);
            head = dummy;
            while (l1 != null && l2 != null){
                if (l1.val<l2.val){
                    dummy.next=l1;
                    l1=l1.next;
                }
                else
                {
                    dummy.next=l2;
                    l2=l2.next;
                }
                dummy=dummy.next;
            }
            if (l1 !=null)
                dummy.next=l1;
            if (l2 !=null)
                dummy.next=l2;

            return head.next;

        }
    public static void display() {
        ListNode current = head;
        while(current != null) {
            System.out.print(current.val + " --> ");
            current = current.next;
        }
        System.out.print("null");
    }


        public static void main(String[] args) {    

            ListNode head1 = new ListNode(-21);
            head1.next = new ListNode(3);
            head1.next.next = new ListNode(5);

            // -21->3->5 LinkedList created
            ListNode head2 = new ListNode(0);
            head2.next = new ListNode(2);
            head2.next.next = new ListNode(44);


            // 0->2->44 LinkedList created
            merge(head1, head2);

            display();
        }
```

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Answer (score 2):

When method merge returns, the `head` of the list is still pointing to the dummy node.

You need to add this line before the return statement:

```
head = head.next;
```

But it's not the most serious mistake - `head` property, as well as all these methods, should **not** be `static`.

Modifier `static` means that the head node is being shared among all the instances of the list, which is not correct.

That will be the correct approach of implementing Singly Linked List. I also suggest you implement such methods as `add()` and `remove()`.

```
class MyList {
    private ListNode head;
    
    private static class ListNode {
        private int val;
        private ListNode next;
        
        public ListNode(int val) {
            this.val = val;
            this.next = null;
        }
    }
    
    public ListNode merge(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
        ListNode dummy = new ListNode(-1);
        head = dummy;
        while (l1 != null && l2 != null) {
            if (l1.val < l2.val) {
                dummy.next = l1;
                l1 = l1.next;
            } else {
                dummy.next = l2;
                l2 = l2.next;
            }
            dummy = dummy.next;
        }
        if (l1 != null)
            dummy.next = l1;
        if (l2 != null)
            dummy.next = l2;
        
        head = head.next;
        return head.next;
    }
    
    public void display() {
        ListNode current = head;
        while (current != null) {
            System.out.print(current.val + " --> ");
            current = current.next;
        }
        System.out.print("null");
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyList mergedList = new MyList();
        
        ListNode head1 = new ListNode(-21);
        head1.next = new ListNode(3);
        head1.next.next = new ListNode(5);
    
        // -21->3->5 LinkedList created
        ListNode head2 = new ListNode(0);
        head2.next = new ListNode(2);
        head2.next.next = new ListNode(44);
    
    
        // 0->2->44 LinkedList created
        mergedList.merge(head1, head2);
    
        mergedList.display();
    }
}
```

*Output:*

```
-21 --> 0 --> 2 --> 3 --> 5 --> 44 --> null
```

Comment: can you provide me some tutorials where I can learn about these better? And thanks a lot

Comment: @Mursalin I can recommend a book, *Algorithms* by Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne. And there's also a course by Robert Sedgewick on *coursera.org*. But it might be very tough for the beginner. Also, to master your knowledge of Java have a look at these [tutorials provided by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)

Answer (score 1):

The `display` method starts printing nodes from the class member variable `head`. In the `merge` method, `head` is initialized by -1, that's the reason why it always prints from -1. A simple way around would be to add an argument in the `display` method.

```
public static void display(ListNode head) {
        ListNode current = head;
        while(current != null) {
            System.out.print(current.val + " --> ");
            current = current.next;
        }
        System.out.print("null");
    }
```

Then store the result of `merge` method in a variable and call the `display` method from `main` method.

```
ListNode res= merge(head1, head2);
display(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your head is pointing to -1 which is dummy node. point your head to the next node.

```
 public static ListNode merge(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
    ListNode dummy = new ListNode(-1);
    head = dummy;
    while (l1 != null && l2 != null) {
        if (l1.val < l2.val) {
            dummy.next = l1;
            l1 = l1.next;
        } else {
            dummy.next = l2;
            l2 = l2.next;
        }
        dummy = dummy.next;
    }
    if (l1 != null)
        dummy.next = l1;
    if (l2 != null)
        dummy.next = l2;
   ##moving you head to next node.
    head = head.next;
    return head.next;

}
```